# How is mail sent without having SMTP service at local Server PC?

Tags: .net, email, smtp

Today i created a mail sending class in .net where I am using the following dotnet class:

> System.Web.Mail.SmtpMail.Send(objMsg);

I run the exe at a server PC where i checked that an SMTP Service is not installed but i am surprised to see that the mail is successfully sent at specified email address from a server.

Can anyone please explain to me how this happens?

Comment: Have you set the [`SmtpServer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mail.smtpmail.smtpserver.aspx) property?

Comment: By the way, `System.Web.Mail` is deprecated, you should use [`System.Net.Mail`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.aspx) instead.

Answer (score 0):

To send a message you will have had to specify email account information that supports SMTP. If you show us more of your code we can point out exactly where that is done. (Disguise your private info.)

So you don't need a locally-installed SMTP server. You just need an email account that is hosted on a mail server that supports SMTP.